# Animating UIScrollView's constraint with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I would like to animate a UIScrollView off the screen, when a button was tapped.

That's the code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

    [scrollViewTopViewConstraint setConstant:-eventScrollView.frame.size.height-100];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

When the same is tapped once again the UIScrollView should be animated back on the screen:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.3 + 0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

    // Standardwert einstellen
    [scrollViewTopViewConstraint setConstant:0];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The problem is when the ScrollView comes back (second button tap) the content Size is reseted. So the user isn't able to scroll, until I set a new contentSize, but it would be much better if it's not reseted.

How I can achieve this?

Best regards from Germany,
Chris

Comment: You can put the setConstant outside of your animation block. Why are you calling [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; in first block but [self.view setNeedsDisplay]; in second block? Why aren't they both [self.view layoutIfNeeded];?

Comment: I just tested it with your advice but the same situation. I think it's Auto Layout which causes this :/

Comment: The code above doesn't seem to be affecting the height of your UIScrollView using autolayout, so your contentSize shouldn't change in the first place. Are you modifying your UIScrollView height somewhere else?